# Twocolumn Revtex-4 figure caption is above the figure

Tags: floats, captions, revtex

Figure captions should be below figure (unlike table captions). But in Revtex4-1 the caption is above the figure. How can one fix this to make it appear below the figure? I'm bumping this should have a solution.

Comment: Maybe this is their standard? Can you provide a minimal example? I don't have the time to make one myself right now.

Comment: It was a simple mistake, I did not know the ordering mattered but indeed it does :) see answer.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the solution to this problem is very easy: Just remember to put the `\caption` **below** the `\includegraphics{}` code! Haha

The following code is what produced the "error" of having the caption above the figure (which one should avoid)

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\caption{This caption is above the figure (please avoid this!)}
\includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{Figure}\label{Fig: Fig1}
\end{figure}
```

While the below code produces the "correct" thing, i.e. having the caption below the figure:

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{Figure}\label{Fig: Fig1}
\caption{This caption is below the figure}
\end{figure}
```